# ORMLite OpenHelper DAO caching in DaoManager?

Tags: android, ormlite

So I have a custom subclass of `OrmLiteSqliteOpenHelper`. I want to use the `ObjectCache` interface to make sure I have identity-mapping from DB rows to in-memory objects, so I override `getDao(...)` as:

```
@Override
public <D extends Dao<T, ?>, T> D getDao(Class<T> arg0) throws SQLException {
    D dao = super.getDao(arg0);
    if (dao.getObjectCache() == null && !UNCACHED_CLASSES.contains(arg0))   
        dao.setObjectCache(InsightOpenHelperManager.sharedCache());
    return dao;
}
```

My understanding is that `super.getDao(Class<T> clazz)` is basically doing a call to `DaoManager.createDao(this.getConnectionSource(),clazz)` behind the scenes, which should find a cached DAO if one exists. However...

```
final DatabaseHelper helpy = CustomOpenHelperManager.getHelper(StoreDatabaseHelper.class);

final CoreDao<Store, Integer> storeDao = helpy.getDao(Store.class);
DaoManager.registerDao(helpy.getConnectionSource(), storeDao);
final Dao<Store,Integer> testDao = DaoManager.createDao(helpy.getConnectionSource(), Store.class);
```

I would expect that (even w/o the `registerDao(...)` call) `storeDao` and `testDao` should be references to the same object. I see this in the Eclipse debugger, however:

[image: Different object IDs]

Also, `testDao`'s object cache is null.

Am I doing something wrong here? Is this a bug?

I do have a custom helper manager, but only because I needed to manage several databases. It's just a hashmap of `Class<? extends DatabaseHelper>` keys to instances.

The reason I need my DAO cached is that I have several foreign collections that are eager and are being loaded by internally-generated DAOs that are not using my global cache and thus are being re-created independently for each collection.

As I was writing this up, I thought I could just have my overridden `helpy.getDao(...)` call through to `DaoManager.createDao(...)`, but that results in the same thing: I still get a different DAO on the second call to `createDao(...)`. This seems to me to be totally against the docs for `DaoManager`.

First, I thought it looked like `registerDao(...)` may be the culprit:

```
public static synchronized void registerDao(ConnectionSource connectionSource, Dao<?, ?> dao) {
        if (connectionSource == null) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("connectionSource argument cannot be null");
        }
        if (dao instanceof BaseDaoImpl) {
            DatabaseTableConfig<?> tableConfig = ((BaseDaoImpl<?, ?>) dao).getTableConfig();
            if (tableConfig != null) {
                tableMap.put(new TableConfigConnectionSource(connectionSource, tableConfig), dao);
                return;
            }
        }
        classMap.put(new ClassConnectionSource(connectionSource, dao.getDataClass()), dao);
    }
```

That `return` on line 230 of the source for `DaoManager` prevents the `classMap` from being updated (since I'm using the pregenerated config files?). When my code hits the second create call, it looks at the `classMap` first, and somehow (against my better understanding) finds a different copy of the DAO living there. Which is super weird, because stepping through the first create, I watched the `classMap` be initialized.

But where would a second DAO possibly come from?

Looking forward to Gray's insight! :-)

Comment: Just pushed out a snapshot release Ben that should fix your issue.  Let me know.  http://ormlite.com/releases/

Comment: Testing now. Hitting an exception creating my custom DAO now, looking into it.

Comment: One of my classes with a one-to-many relationship w/ `Store` is throwing an exception at `FieldType:287`. It believes it's a primitive type because `dataPersister` is an instance of `IntType`? Was not seeing this under 4.33.

Comment: Please send me mail via http://256.com/gray/email/

Comment: Thought I had accepted. My bad. I actually just reworked my model around it IIRC, since I was originally getting that weird bug. I appreciate all your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Ben mentioned, there is some internal DAO creation which is screwing things up but I think he may have uncovered a bug.

Under Android, [ORMLite](http://ormlite.com/) tries to use some magic reflection to build the DAOs given the **horrible** reflection performance under all but the most recent Android OS versions.  Whenever the user asks for the DAO for class `Store` (for example), the magic reflection fu is creating one DAO but internally it is using another one.  I've created the follow bug:

> https://sourceforge.net/tracker/?func=detail&aid=3487674&group_id=297653&atid=1255989

I changed the way the DAOs get created to do a better job of using the reflection output.  The changes were pushed out in the 4.34.  This release revamps (and simplifies) the internal DAO creation and caching.  It should fix the issue.

> http://ormlite.com/releases/

Comment: My gut reaction would be to have a registry (maybe a `HashSet`) in `DaoManager` that, upon failing the required `lookupDao` calls, the `createDao` method could register that it is in process of creating a DAO for class X before it dives into the actual creation process. Any dependent DAO's that would like to reference the unfinished DAO (and are generated during the recursive process) could have a listener or somesuch that sets up the reference once the recursion (and thus creation) is complete?

Comment: I have such a registry but there are differences between those hand configured and class configured with annotations.  The reflection code uses the hand configured classes hence the internal confusion.

Answer (score 0):

Just kidding. Looks like what may be happening is that my `Store` object DAO initialization is creating DAO's for foreign connections (that I set to foreignAutoRefresh) and then recursively creating another DAO for itself (since the DAO creation that started this has not completed, and thus has yet to be registered w/ the `DaoManager`).

Looks like this has to do w/ the recursion noted in `BaseDaoImpl.initialize()`.

I'm getting Inception flashbacks just looking at this.